# Validating a text box

Tags: php, html, validation

I have got a standard html form. However, people have found a way through it by typing it shortened urls into the textboxes. How can I validate against it in a simple way. Thanks.

Code:

```
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
Firstname: <br> <input type="text" name="Firstname" value="<?php  echo $Firstname; ?>"><br><br>
Surname: <br> <input type="text" name="Surname" value="<?php  echo $Surname; ?>"><br><br>
Email Address: <br> <input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php  echo $Email; ?>"><br><br>
Username: <br> <input type="text" name="Username" value="<?php  echo $Username; ?>"><br><br>
Password: <br> <input type="password" name="Password"><br><br>
Password Again: <br> <input type="password" name="password_again"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Register"></form>
```

Comment: You have to do validation on the server, there's nothing you can do to prevent users from bypass client-side validation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

php has a great native function called filter_var http://php.net/filter_var

there are lots of validation filters http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

i would run the FILTER_VALIDATE_URL and see if the user is submitting a url, and if so, return an error.

EDIT; requested example code

```
<?
function isUrl($var) {
    return (filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) ? true : false;
}

if($_POST) {
    $error = false;
    $err_msg = '';

    //get variables safely
    $Firstname = isset($_POST['Firstname']) ? $_POST['Firstname'] : '';
    $Surname = isset($_POST['Surname']) ? $_POST['Surname'] : '';
    $Email = isset($_POST['Email']) ? $_POST['Email'] : '';
    $Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';
    $Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';
    $Password_again = isset($_POST['Password_again']) ? $_POST['Password_again'] : '';

    //null checks
    if($Firstname == '' || $Surname == '' || $Email == '' || $Username == '' || $Password == '' || $Password_agin == '') {
        $error = true;
        $err_msg = 'Missing required values';
    } 

    //password match
    if($Password != $Password_again) {
        $error = true;
        $err_msg = 'Passwords do not match';        
    }

    //email validity
    if(filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false) {
        $error = true;
        $err_msg = 'Invalid email'; 
    }

    //url checks
    if(isUrl($Firstname) || isUrl($Surname) || isUrl($Username)) {
        $error = true;
        $err_msg = 'Urls are not allowed';      
    }

    //final step
    if(!$error) {
        //save info to db
    } else {
        die($err_msg);
    }

} else {
    die('nothing sent');
}
?>
```

this assumes a few things. you will need to handle what to do in the "die" context yourself.
hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If it mucks  up the system your best bet is to do the validation at server-side in register.php.  You could add JavaScript but someone could simply turn it off, or avoid in other ways, and you'd have the same problem.  Server-side validation is necessary if it has an impact on the system.

Comment: Is there no way of just not allowing certain characters like <

Comment: There are ways to do that on the client-side but there also ways around it on the client-side, so you have to clean and/or reject them on the server, after the POST, and before inserting them into your DB

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to have both Javascript validation and server side validation.
Javascript validation is instantaneous and can help validate the form without repeated calls to your server but as Matt said it can be turned off or messed with.
Server side validation is the more secure validation but its heavier on resources and slower if you have to make repeated calls.
This is why its good to have both - validate client side and once that is passed validate server side.
sample tutorial on simple javascript validation: http://www.elated.com/articles/form-validation-with-javascript/